# Buffer Error: && JSON Parser Error:

Tags: php, android, json, parsing, buffer

So im getting 2 errors on my android app when i run it. first-/Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
second-/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of ...Seems ive read countless questions pertaining to the same problem  but none that have help my situation. Im passing the username from shared preference to my php so i can query from DB on regards to current user. Ive ran the php from web and everything seems on the up and up. Hopefully someone can help spot my error...heres the code
All_Content.java

```
package com.example.mrbuknahsty.annovoteexdb;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mr.buknahsty on 5/10/2016.
 */
public class All_Content extends ListActivity
{
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contentList;

sessionManager session;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_content =   
"http://www.lkirkpatrick.btcwsd.com/anno/all.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";
private static final String TAG_T_ID = "t_id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray contents = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_content);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    contentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

}

        /**
         * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
         * */
        class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(All_Content.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * getting All products from url
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                session = new sessionManager(getApplicationContext());

                session.checkLogin();

                HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

                // name
                String uName = user.get(sessionManager.KEY_NAME);

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>
 (1);
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_content,   
 uName+"GET", params);

                if(json!=null) {
                    // do something
                    Log.d("results: ", json.toString());


                    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse


                    try {
                        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 1) {
                            // products found
                            // Getting Array of Products
                            contents = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTENT);

                            // looping through All Products
                            for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject c = contents.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Storing each json item in variable
                                String id = c.getString(TAG_T_ID);
                                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                                // creating new HashMap
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new   
 HashMap<String, String>();

                                // adding each child node to HashMap key =>   
 value
                                map.put(TAG_T_ID, id);
                                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                contentList.add(map);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // no products found
                            // Launch Add New product Activity
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    All_Content.class);
                            // Closing all previous activities
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                All_Content.this, contentList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_T_ID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                                new int[] { R.id.t_id, R.id.name });
                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    }
```

JSONParser class

```
package com.example.mrbuknahsty.annovoteexdb;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mr.buknahsty on 5/10/2016.
 */
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + 
e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.i("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

}
}
```

all.php

```
<?php
require_once 'get_all.php';

$uName = "";


if(isset($_POST['uName']))
{
$uName = $_POST['uName'];
}


// Instance of a Topic class
$get_AllObject = new get_All();

// Registration of new topic
if(!empty($uName))
{

$json_registration = $get_AllObject->getAll($uName);

echo json_encode($json_registration);
}

?>
```

and my get_all.php

```
<?php
include_once 'error.php';

class get_All{

private $db;
private $db_table = "topics";

public function __construct()
{
    $this->db = new DbConnect();
}


public function getAll($uName)
{   
    $response = array();

    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    //USERS TABLE
    //query to get current logged in user_id
    $un = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$uName'";

    //running query
    $unResults = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $un);

    //get user_id results from query **CREDIT GOES TO BEN LAPAZ FOR THIS..
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($unResults))
    {
        $id = ($row['user_id']);
    }

    //now i have current user_id
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //CREATED_TOPICS TABLE
    //query to get all data from created_topics thats under user_id that 
matches current user_id
    $t_id = "SELECT * FROM created_topics WHERE user_id = '$id'";

    //running query
    $t_id_Results = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $t_id);

    //get topic_id results from query 
    while ($rowT = mysqli_fetch_array($t_id_Results))
    {
        $id_T = ($rowT['topic_id']);
    }

    //now i have all topic_ids' for current user
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //TOPICS TABLE
    //query to get all data from topics thats has to do with topic_ids from   
previous query
    $userContent = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_id = '$id_T'";

    $userContentResults = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(),$userContent);

    //running query
   if ($userContentResults && mysqli_num_rows($userContentResults) > 0) 
   {
        // looping through all results
        // products node
        $response["content"] = array();

        //get content results from query 
        while ($rowContent = mysqli_fetch_array($userContent))
        {
             $content = array();
             $content["topic_id"] = $row["topic_id"];
             $content["topic_name"] = $row["topic_name"];
             $content["content"] = $row["content"];
             $content["code"] = $row["code"];
             $content["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
             $content["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];

            // push single content into final response array
            array_push($response["content"], $content);
          }
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } 
        else {
            // no products found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No products found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
}
}
?>
```

and log///this is all Im getting

```
05-12 08:34:41.728 12650-12740/com.example.mrbuknahsty.annovoteexdb   
I/Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock  
==  null

05-12 08:34:41.728 12650-12740/com.example.mrbuknahsty.annovoteexdb   
I/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at   
character 0 of 
05-12 08:34:41.828 12650-12650/com.example.mrbuknahsty.annovoteexdb  
I/Timeline: 
Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41b644f8 time:47813028
```

Comment: Regarding you JSON parse error. In your php code you have the getAll method of your class echoing the json encoded variable instead of returning it to the caller.

Comment: thanks @Andreas, I changed it to return but still same errors

Comment: I believe the error is coming from ** JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_content,   
 uName+"GET", params);** I removed to uName and hardcoded the value in my get_all.php file and the errors went away but i get this now **results:: {"content":[],"success":1}** and nothing showing up...Any ideas on why its showing content:[]?